# How to inject the same service in 2 components which interact dynamically with it in Angular2

Tags: json, typescript, angular, angular2-directives, angular2-services

I have an application which includes the action of changing the image of background by choosing an image from a collection of examples, the idea is to write a service whiche parse the json list links of images and defines the one for background .
so i have a component 1 : for view seleted images
a component 2 : for loading images + action of one image selection
a service : for changing the image selected

the problem that the service set the first image which is imposed by default in the service itself and cannot change it when i make the action of choosing a one betwen the images parsed by the service and viewed within component 2, specifically this lign in the view of component 2 :

```
<img class="contentSizes" src={{BackService.imageLink}}>
```

component 1 :

```
@Component({
    selector: 'content',
    templateUrl: 'content.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['content.component.css'],
    providers:[BackgroundService],
    directives: [FORM_DIRECTIVES],

})
export class ContentComponent {

    constructor(public BackService : BackgroundService )
    {

    }
}
```

and the template :

```
<div>
    <img class="contentSizes"  src={{BackService.imageLink}}>
</div>
```

Component 2 : (loading images by service and selecting one to make it as background

```
@Component({
    selector: 'housepic',
    templateUrl: '.housepic.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['housepic.component.css'],
    providers:[BackgroundService],
    viewProviders:[HTTP_PROVIDERS],
    directives:[ContentComponent]

})
export class HousepicComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy{

    images_list;



    constructor(
        public BackService : BackgroundService)
    {
      this.BackService = BackService;


    }



    onSelectImage(lien){
        console.log("housepic"+lien.toString());
        this.BackService.imageChange(lien);
    }

    ngOnInit(){
        this.BackService.getjson().subscribe(people => this.images_list = people);
    }

    ngOnDestroy(){

    }

}
```

and the template:

```
<div class="accordian">
    <ul>
        <li *ngFor="#img of images_list">
            <div class="image_title">
                <a href="#">Exemple</a>
            </div>

            <a (click)="onSelectImage(img.image)" >
                <img  src="{{img.image}}" style="height: 320px ; width: 640px"/>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and the service :

```
import {Injectable,EventEmitter,Output} from 'angular2/core';
import {Http} from "angular2/http";
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';



@Injectable()
export class BackgroundService{



    constructor (public http : Http){

        this.http= http;
        /*this.imageLink = '../../../dev/backgrounds/int4.png';*/
        console.log("lien initial"+ this.getImage());
        this.imageChange('../../../dev/backgrounds/int4.png');

    }

    /*background variable link*/
    public _imageLink :string


    get 
    set imageLink(value:string) {
        console.log("nnnnn"+value)
        this._imageLink = value;
    }


    /*parsing des images temoins */
    getjson(){
        return this.http.get('dev/JsonData/maisonsImages.json')
            .map(res => res.json())
    }



    /*action de changement de l image */

    public imageChange (lien:string):void{

        this._imageLink=lien;


        console.log("imageLink = "+this._imageLink)
        console.log("le lien recu = "+lien);



    }

    /*recuperer l image selectionne */
    getImage(){
        console.log("yyyy"+this._imageLink)
        return this._imageLink;
    }

imageLink():string {
        return this._imageLink;
    }

    set imageLink(value:string) {
        console.log("nnnnn"+value)
        this._imageLink = value;
    }


    /*parsing des images temoins */
    getjson(){
        return this.http.get('dev/JsonData/maisonsImages.json')
            .map(res => res.json())
    }



    /*action de changement de l image */

    public imageChange (lien:string):void{

        this._imageLink=lien;


        console.log("imageLink = "+this._imageLink)
        console.log("le lien recu = "+lien);



    }

    /*recuperer l image selectionne */
    getImage(){
        console.log("yyyy"+this._imageLink)
        return this._imageLink;
    }
```

and finaly the json file of data (links of images) to be parsed by the service:

```
[
  { "id": 1, "image": "../../../dev/backgrounds/int0.jpg" },
  { "id": 2, "image": "../../../dev/backgrounds/int1.jpg" },
  { "id": 3, "image": "../../../dev/backgrounds/int2.jpg" },
  { "id": 4, "image": "../../../dev/backgrounds/int3.jpg" },
  { "id": 5, "image": "../../../dev/backgrounds/int4.png" }

]
```

also my file boot.ts :

```
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {AppComponent} from "./app.component";
import {ROUTER_PROVIDERS} from "angular2/router";
import {MATERIAL_PROVIDERS} from 'ng2-material/all';
import {BackgroundService} from "./services/background/BackgroundService";
import {ROUTER_PROVIDERS, LocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategy} from 'angular2/router';
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS} from "angular2/http";
import {provide} from "angular2/core";



bootstrap(AppComponent,[ROUTER_PROVIDERS,HTTP_PROVIDERS,BackgroundService,MATERIAL_PROVIDERS,
    provide(LocationStrategy, { useClass: HashLocationStrategy })
]);
```

Comment: to note i'm using angular2 beta 9

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't add the service to providers of each component

```
  providers:[BackgroundService],
```

This way each component will get it's own instance.
Instead add it only on a common parent. To share it with the whole application add it to the `AppComponent` (root component) or `bootstrap(AppComponent, [BackgroundService]);`

Comment: @firasKoubaa if it worked you should accept the answer.